# Unable to show/hide the drop down based on Radio button selected

Tags: wicket

I am new to wicket framework,
My Requirement is the following.
In the form,I need to display 2 radio buttons(either by using RadioGroup or RadioChoice) and a dropdown list.
for radio buttons, just need to name,show/hide.
when i click on the show/hide,the response is not picking up.
Here is my code,
Java,

```
private DropDownChoice<String> ddc;
private RadioChoice<String> radioChoice;
private String selected;

/* creating a radio choice */
        List<String> options = new ArrayList();
        options.add("show");
        options.add("hide");

        radioChoice = new RadioChoice("group", new 

PropertyModel<String>(this, "selected"), options) {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged() {
                // super.onSelectionChanged();
                // if ("show".equals(getValue())) {
                // ddc.setVisible(true);
                // }
                // if ("hide".equals(getValue())) {
                // ddc.setVisible(false);
                // ddc.clearInput();
                // ddc.detach();
                // ddc.remove();

                ddc.setEnabled(false);
                // }

            }
        };


        add(radioChoice);

        /* creating a drop down list */
        List<String> mobiles = new ArrayList();

        mobiles.add("LG");
        mobiles.add("oppo");
        mobiles.add("oneplus");

        ddc = new DropDownChoice("mobiles", mobiles);
        ddc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(ddc);
```

HTML code,

```
<span wicket:id="group"></span><br/>
            <select wicket:id="mobiles"></select>
```

but its not working,
I need to click on 1 radio button to show dropdown,and other to hide the dropown.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to overwrite `wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()` in your `RadioChoice` and return `true`. Otherwise the JavaScript for calling the `onSelectionChanged()` will not be generated.

One thing to consider: Since using `onSelectionChanged()` results in a page reload, you could instead try adding an `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` to your RadioChoice, so that only your DropDownChoice gets updated when clicking one of the RadioButtons:

```
radioChoice.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        /* Your code here */

        // Add DropDownChoice to the Ajax Response
        target.add(ddc);
    }
});
```